# My website is being forwarded to another url after 15 seconds

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I'm not sure if I was hacked, but my website gets forwarded to a blogger website after 15 seconds.  Here is the URL 
https://www.blogger.com/blogin.g?blogspotURL=http://get-yourfree-giftnow.blogspot.com/2016/05/get-your-free-gift-now.html 
I certainly didn't insert that in the code and ipage my server host said they have nothing to do with it.  Please help.  Thank you in advance.
-John

Answer (score 1):

Heres a few ideas to start with:

If you haven't already used https://www.magereport.com to scan for known vulnerabilites it'd be a great place to start with advice on how to fix the issue(s) and will quickly scan them for you.

If that doesnt find it then I'd recommend a tool like http://www.telerik.com/fiddler to see exactly what happens at the http request-response level to see where the issue might be coming from. Either code or DNS. It may give you some url or unique identifier that is the redirect target to search for in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .htaccess file in the root folder of your Magento installation. Could be something in there, or look for any unusual php files in the root folder of your Magento site. Probably something in one of those two items.